# How to do a simple normal probability plot on Linux?

Tags: data-visualization

I'm a total newbie here. Hope this makes some sense!

I have a two-dimensional dataset. One dimension is composed of unordered
strings. At the moment, they're not important. For all uses and purposes,
they may as well be random strings.

The dimension I'm interested is composed of *monetary* floating point
numbers.

What I'm trying to say is that my data looks like the following:

```
[['blablabla', 1234.5678], ['blebleble', 9012.3456], ..., ['hahaha': 7890.1234], ['hehehe': 5678.9012]]
```

I would like to draw a *Normal Probability Plot* for this data, as in this
website: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/normprpl.htm

What is a quick, simple way of doing a *Normal Probability Plot* for this
data in Linux?

I'm on an Ubuntu variant. I've got setups for both node.js and Python. I'm
OK with JavaScript charting libraries. If need be, I can also look into
installing R, Octave, etc.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

While implementation specific details are usually considered off topic, I can give general advice that should work for you.

If you have access to an inverse normal cdf, you can plot the sorted data ($x_{(i)}$) against $\Phi^{-1}(p_i)$ where $p_i = \frac{i-\alpha}{n+1-2\alpha}$. A common choice for $\alpha$ is $\frac{3}{8}$ (Blom's compromise value). If you want the median of the order statistics (like the plot you link to) then $\alpha=\frac13$ would be closer ($\alpha=0.3175$ is also used for the median, though Filliben (1975) suggested changing the $p$'s for the first and last order statistics to $p_n=\frac12^n$ and $p_1=1-p_n$) but it will make hardly any difference to the appearance of the plot.

If you don't have access to an inverse normal cdf there's a couple of Tukey-lambda approximations that do reasonably well. They're of the form $\Phi^{-1}(u)\approx a[u^\lambda-(1-u)^\lambda]$ with either $a\approx 4.91$ and $\lambda=0.14$ or $a\approx 5.06$ (some have 5.05) and $\lambda=0.135$ (though if you're just using it to draw a plot, the exact choice of $a$ isn't really that important).

In terms of the visual appearance of the plot the values are generally indistinguishable. Here's a plot using the inverse normal cdf and the two Tukey lambda approximations (the 4th plot is all three superimposed ... almost exact to the pixel -- this is at n=20 but the same holds across a wide range of sample sizes).

[image: Three normal probability plots]
(This plot generated in R but it's immaterial to the point being made)

The advantage of the Tukey lambda approximation is that you don't need as much functionality from your libraries so it's easier to implement on fairly basic platforms.

So all you need now is something capable of plotting a scatterplot.

Answer (score 1):

A python implementation using [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html). Less complete and lacking pre-processing code:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.graphics.gofplots import qqplot

data = np.array([1234.5678, 9012.3456, 7890.1234, 5678.9012])

qqplot(data, line = 'q')
```

[image]